# Display and Map Multiple Keys and its object data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON file which I need to map and display but I am not sure how to map the structure like this as this is a bit different.

**Below is my JSON file:**

```
var data = {
"megamenu": [
{
      "name": "level1.2",
      "link": "#",
      "multilevel": {
        "A": [
          {
            "name": "A-one",
            "link": "#"
          }
        ],
        "B": [
          {
            "name": "B-one",
            "link": "#"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
]
}
```

**Map Function:**

```
{data.megamenu.map((menuitem, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{Object.entries(menuitem.multilevel).length}</li>
))}
```

Following is the sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8in6yq

I want to create a structure something like this:

```
<ul>
        <li>level1.2
        <ul>
            <li>multilevel
            <ul>
                <li>A
              <ul>
                    <li>A-one</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>B
                <ul>
                    <li>B-one</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Note: I know I can change the structure to object and not array but this is something I cannot handle and change. So have to manage with this structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So why can't you do something like:

```
const Multilevel = ({multilevel}) => (
    <ul>
        {Object.keys(multilevel).map(key => (<li key={key}>{key} /* etc*/</li>))}
    </ul>
);

{data.megamenu.map((menuitem, index) => (
    <li key={menuitem.name}>
        {menuitem.name}
        <ul>
            <li>multilevel
                <Multilevel multilevel={menuitem.multilevel}/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
))}
```

That's a bit complex, and I advice you to separate your lists to different components to make code readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is still throwing the error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, link}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` Please check this [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8in6yq](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8in6yq)

Comment: @H.Husain sure, it sould be `Object.keys`, chck the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/019bLfn5/)

Comment: I strongly advise you not to use the `index` as the key of your mapped elements. If the names are unique (it looks like they are), you will be better off using the name property as the `key` instead.

Comment: @Josep I totally agree with you, I changed the key to name. Just missed that :)

Comment: @Andrew : Thanks for the fiddle, Can we map and display the object inside the key. For example : `"A": [
          {
            "name": "A-one",
            "link": "#"
          }
        ],`

`name`

Comment: @H.Husain, eeeeeh, I just tried to show you direction :) Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/019bLfn5/3/) and read comments I left in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through inner `multilevels`

```
{data.megamenu.map((menuitem, index) => (
    const innnerItemsDOM = menuitem.multilevel.map((item, index) =>{
       return <li>
                <ul>
                  <li>item.name</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
    })

    return <li> level1.2
     {innnerItemsDOM}
    </li>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any sample for creating the inner DOM ? The inner DOM also should be the key name and object name inside the key. ( name and link )